# Pseudo real-time data stream javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, real-time

Update: I am getting the impression that this is not even the right website to post this. If someone can point me in the right direction, I'd be appreciative...

I have an existing PHP+MySQL application that wasn't built to render "real-time" or similarly live-style data. But now I need to build in a way to pull nearly real-time data into the application and keep the data on the page fresh. This live data is only for 1 page in the application.

Looked at things like socket.io and PHP-based websockets libraries, but it seemed like overkill because the data is basically coming from 1 source and being delivered to 1 person (the client). Multiple other users could have this process running, but each one would bring their own data endpoint. That's... like a year down the road. But good to think about. Would ideally have hundreds, or thousands of users on the system, pulling their live-ish data. So I want this to be as streamlined and low-impact as possible.

Users must be authenticated and authorized to consume the data. This is already baked into the current system.

The API to get the data (which has already been built by another vendor) is also NOT streaming. It's set on a 20-second cron, so the new data is available every 20 seconds, which satisfies the client's needs.

My current plan is to do something like this...

1. Data is pulled on a cron every 20 seconds, organized, and stored into the database (complete)
2. Adjust #1 so it also does any additional proprietary calculations on data AND compiles + writes a JSON file on the server (unique to the user) which is the exact data needed for the front end (DB data is needed for other pages)
3. Create small PHP-based service which validates a client-provided JWT and reads the JSON file out
4. Write AJAX front end to poll endpoint from #3 every X seconds using a JWT for authorization

This all seems sort of like I might be reinventing the wheel, or missing something. The fact that this is an existing PHP based application (LAMP) does have some limiting factors, but I feel like there's got to be a more efficient way to handle this... It's pretty new to me. Also, I'm open to other technologies that'll run on the LAMP stack, if it'll make things better.

Comment: There are 4 technologies that do what you want: AJAX, WebSockets, Server-Sent Events and WebRTC. However, I highly recommend start with a simple AJAX - premature optimization is evil.

Comment: This question is too broad. It's also off-topic to ask for suggestions about technologies/software etc. If you have a plan, make some attempts and come back if you run into some _specific_ issue with your attempts.

Comment: I think it's dumb to call asking for software suggestions "off-topic", but then again, it's not up to me. If I'm rebuilding an existing package or library from scratch and don't need to, I'd love for someone to tell me "hey, that's exactly what xyz does". So, is it "too broad" or "off-topic" to ask someone to recommend a different place to post this question, if it doesn't fit the requirements here?

Comment: It says so in the guidelines: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_. Suggestions risks flame wars about what technology is the best, which is not what this site is for. SO is for when you're having specific issues with existing code (which requires you to have chosen a tech first).

Comment: @David that would make comment sections burst with recommendations of software which quality couldn't be assessed. I've seen such threads myself, often they don't make any sense.

Comment: I understand the reasoning... but that doesn't help someone trying to decide which technology best fits their situation. Which is what I'm doing. I also see recommendations for libraries and technology all over the site, so it's not like I'm totally off-base here. Anyway... that's fine. I'll figure it out.

Comment: _"but that doesn't help someone trying to decide which technology best fits their situation"_ - I get that, but Stackoverflow is simply the wrong place to ask these kind of questions since the outcome usually ends up to be anything but constructive.

Comment: @Magnus Then can you recommend a different community? I wasn't joking about that one. I need to gather opinions, and I don't personally know anyone familiar with this type of scenario.

Comment: As for socket.io you could [chat with them on slack](https://slackin-socketio.now.sh): *"Hi guys, I think that socket.io would be overkill ..."*, for many other frameworks/libraries there are usually respective communities. I hope it helps, good luck with your project!

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could try over at [Quora](https://sv.quora.com/). I've never posted anything there myself but I've seen it recommended by others in similar situations.

Answer (score -1):

I would say go for the API solution in the beginning :) Since it fits the architecture more and is for sure the least amount of work. Also if there will be problem with the "live" feeling of the data you can fix it by polling more often or introducing long polling, assuming you change the cron job time.

I mean in the end it is all about impact for the time spent, don't start implement features that customers don't care about :)

The biggest problem to solve is to implement it in a way that fits your requirements and is somewhat future extendable. You still have to deal with issues like resolution, time outs, reducing server processing when requesting data and so on!

Answer (score -1):

For me, if you need to maintain a global service state because a single client(s) request could affect all other connected client request(s) then most all server-side scripting languages are not the best choice! Also to further add, if you plan on implementing something like this with PHP, you will be setting your self up for a living nightmare! Why, because simply put, PHP(s) socket(s) implementation is that bad!